# How to get Exception source “Activity Description name”

Tags: automation, uipath

When exceptions occur in a UIPath project I have an email that is sent out with the exception info included. There seems to be an issue though where I can only see where the error occured by looking at the selector information such as:

```
Cannot find the UI element corresponding to this selector: 
<html app='chrome.exe' title='Microsoft Dynamics GP' />
<webctrl aaname='Add' idx='1'
    parentid='a00000000000000008549000000030009000000000001000000000000' tag='DIV' />
```

This info and the stack trace or any other info is not really helpful for quickly finding the source of the problem. I have looked through the UIPath documentation and forum and found only the [this question](https://forum.uipath.com/t/how-to-get-exception-source-activity-description-name/4414), which seemed to point to using the exception.Source to show the name of the activity where the error occurred. exception.Source only returns “UiPath.Core.Activities” though instead of "Type into Copy Job# 'INPUT'" in the following example:

[image: exception issue]

This obviously causes a big problem with exception handling. How can I easily return the source with each exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your selector fails, you will end up with a new object of type `UiPath.Core.SelectorNotFoundException`. However, until the team at UiPath decides to add the `Display Name` into the inner exception, there is little you can do in this particular case.

Take the following example - the first line shows the Inner Exception, and the second one in red is essentially just the exception being rethrown. Note that only the latter one contains the `Display Name` property.

[image: Output Window]

The `Source` itself will usually be of type `UiPath.Core.Activities`, but since this is just the type's name, we don't have any link to the faulting object. Here's what you can do:

1. Add some details to your exception. You don't want to do this for each activity, but you could have certain blocks of try-catches (example: logging into the system consists of three individual activites, and they reside in one block). [image: Exception Details]
2. Rethrow the exception. That way the Display Name will end up in the execution log file.

Comment: Ok, that is a nice trick to know. This helps for being able to at least review logs to find exactly where the error happened since I was already rethrowing errors. It would really be nice if UIPath provided this error detail so that I could easily email myself everything. Either way, this will work for an alternate way to find the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @MUlferts - Submit an idea! - https://forum.uipath.com/c/user-voice/ideas